# Binding checkBoxList on Razor Page with Viewdata

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I want to bind a CheckBoxList on Razor page with Viewdata.I have the following code on my Controller Index:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
 {
var testSections = new List<ReassignmentSectionLookup>();
testSections = await _employeeService.GetTestSections();
 ViewData["testSections"] = new SelectList(testSections, "ReassignmentSectionLookupID", "Section");
return View();
}
```

I have the following on my razor page:

```
 <div class="form-group row">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        Select Test: <br />
                        @{
                            var select = ViewData["testSections"] as SelectList;
                            if (select != null && select.ToList().Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in select.ToList())
                                {
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="@item.Value" @(Html.Raw(item.Selected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> @item.Text  <br />
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    </div>
```

When I hover over select, I can see 12 items in the select:

[image]

when I hover over select.ToList().Count I get an error saying "system.NullReferenceException". I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I can see the data in the select. below is the screen shot of the error:
[image]

If I try doing select.Items.ToList() then I am getting this error:
[image]

When using this line:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="@item.Value" @(Html.Raw(item.Selected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> @item.Text  <br />
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: It should be `select.Items.ToList().Count > 0`

Comment: If I do select.Items.ToList().Count then I am getting another error. I pasted the screen shot of the error  in my original post

Comment: Try putting `@using System.Linq` on the top of your cshtml.

Comment: Just curious, why not return a List with model contains both "ReassignmentSectionLookupID" and "Section" property instead of using `SelectList`? For my perspective, `SelectList` is used when you are rendering the data set as drop-down list with tag-helper (asp-items) or HtmlHelper (`@Html.DropdownList()`).

Comment: Can you give me a n example for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, I would say `SelectList` is not suitable as it is used to render the items for the select/drop-down list with either tag helper (`asp-items`) or HtmlHelper (`@Html.DropdownList()`).

1. Create a model class for the data set.

```cs
public class ReassignmentSectionLookupOption
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

2. Instead of returning the data as `SelectList` in `ViewData`, return as `List<ReassignmentSectionLookupOption>` type.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var testSections = await _employeeService.GetTestSections();
 
    ViewData["testSections"] = testSections
        .Select(x => new ReassignmentSectionLookupOption { Value = x.ReassignmentSectionLookupID, Text = x.Section })
        .ToList();

    return View();
}
```

3. In View, cast the `ViewData` as `List<ReassignmentSectionLookupOption>`. And you can use `.Any()` to check whether the list is not empty.

```
@{
    var testSections = ViewData["testSections"] as List<ReassignmentSectionLookupOption>;
    if (testSections != null && testSections.Any())
    {
        foreach (var item in testSections)
        {
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="@item.Value" @(Html.Raw(item.Selected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> @item.Text <br />
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting a small error when I put this line in razor view: <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="@item.Value" @(Html.Raw(item.Selected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> @item.Text  <br />
        }  I put the screen shot in my original post.

Comment: Hi, you don't need the `item.Selected` part by the way. If you keen, then you need to add `Selected` property in `ReassignmentSectionLookupOption` class.

Comment: ok, got it. When I do HTTPPost, I don't see the checked box values. Since this is a separate question, I can post this question separately.